# WAV/RIFF - wrong file size in file header?

Tags: audio, hex, decimal, wav

According to the WAV/RIFF file specification: http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html 5-8 bytes in the header are size of the overall file minus 8 bytes. For example:

```
52 49 46 46 RIFF
24 04 06 00 $Ř..   <-- file size
57 41 56 45 WAVE
66 6D 74 20 fmt
10 00 00 00 
01 00 01 00 
44 AC 00 00 
88 58 01 00
02 00 10 00 
64 61 74 61
```

Hex 24 04 06 00 equals 604243456 bytes decimal, but in real the file size (reported by the OS) is 394284 bytes. Am I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found it. All data in the RIFF/WAV file is stored using Little Endian and I was reading it as Big Endain. Reading is as Little Endian:

```
Big Endian:
24 04 06 00

Little Endian:
00060424
```

It gives 394276 bytes decimal + 8 bytes for ID and RIFF chunk size = **394284 bytes** :)